# Application is getting killed without any reason. Suspecting high BSS. How to debug it?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, memory

I have been running my application successfully in CentOs6.6. Recently, the hardware(motherboard and RAM) was updated and my application is getting killed now without any reason at all.

```
[root@localhost PktBlaster]# ./PktBlaster
Killed
```

File and ldd output

```
[root@localhost PktBlaster]# file PktBlaster
PktBlaster: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, not stripped

[root@localhost PktBlaster]# ldd PktBlaster
not a dynamic executable
```

Output of strace

```
[root@localhost PktBlaster]# strace ./PktBlaster
execve("./PktBlaster", ["./PktBlaster"], [/* 30 vars */] <unfinished ...>
+++ killed by SIGKILL +++
Killed
```

GDB

```
[root@localhost PktBlaster]# gdb PktBlaster
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x43d664: file VTP.c, line 544.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /root/Veryx/PktBlaster/PktBlaster 
During startup program terminated with signal SIGKILL, Killed.
```

While debugging, observed that the bss memory is huge(~6GB). The system has 4GB RAM and I think this could be the reason for the issue.

```
[root@localhost PktBlaster_1Gig]# size build/unix/bin/PktBlaster 
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
 375551   55936 6747541120  6747972607  19235e3ff   build/unix/bin/PktBlaster
```

The application contains many `.h` files and many datastructures and so it is difficult for me to identify why BSS is been raised to 6GB.

Could anyone please suggest how to identify which file is causing this? or any other easier way to debug this?

Comment: What is the output of `ulimit -d` and `swapon -s` ?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick `unlimited` and `1560572` respectively

Comment: Did you check dmesg output?

Comment: @user1641854 yes, there was nothing about the killing of the application.

Comment: Did you check LD_DEBUG=all /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /path/to/exe output ?

Comment: @user1641854 I don't know what that would do. Could you please explain the purpose of it. This is the output :  `[root@localhost PktBlaster]# LD_DEBUG=all /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  /root/Veryx/PktBlaster/PktBlaster
       851: file=/root/Veryx/PktBlaster/PktBlaster [0];  generating link map
/root/Veryx/PktBlaster/PktBlaster: error while loading shared libraries: /root/Veryx/PktBlaster/PktBlaster: cannot map zero-fill pages: Cannot allocate memory`

Comment: 4GB of RAM and 1.5GB of swap might not be enough virtual memory for such a large program. Might try `nm --print-size --size-sort  PktBlaster | awk '$3 == "b" || $3 == "B"'` and see which symbols have large sizes. If you can't reduce the variables' size, you can try adding more swap space (or RAM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that problem really is huge BSS size.
I have asked you to show output of `LD_DEBUG=all /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /path/to/exe` in comments.

`/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` is runtime linker which is used by OS to load your binary in process memory during `execve` system call. Runtime linker is responsible for parsing executable format, loading all sections and dependencies in memory, performing all required relocations and so on.
Setting environment variable `LD_DEBUG` to all we instruct runtime linker to generate debug output.

> [root@localhost PktBlaster]# LD_DEBUG=all /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
>   /root/Veryx/PktBlaster/PktBlaster
>   851:  file=/root/Veryx/PktBlaster/PktBlaster [0]; generating link map
>   /root/Veryx/PktBlaster/PktBlaster: error while loading shared
>   libraries: /root/Veryx/PktBlaster/PktBlaster: cannot map zero-fill
>   pages: Cannot allocate memory

Searching for this error message in source code of runtime linker(glibc-2.17 elf/dl-load.c, lines ~1400) we see:

```
1393         if (zeroend > zeropage)
1394           {
1395         /* Map the remaining zero pages in from the zero fill FD.  */
1396         caddr_t mapat;
1397         mapat = __mmap ((caddr_t) zeropage, zeroend - zeropage,
1398                 c->prot, MAP_ANON|MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED,
1399                 -1, 0);
1400         if (__builtin_expect (mapat == MAP_FAILED, 0))
1401           {
1402             errstring = N_("cannot map zero-fill pages");
1403             goto call_lose_errno;
1404           }
```

dl-loader is in process of loading BSS segment, which by optimizations is stored in binary format as just number of bytes, that must be initialized to zero. Loader tries to allocate through `mmap` zero initialized memory block(MAP_ANONYMOUS) and get error from the OS:

```
 15 #define ENOMEM      12  /* Out of memory */
```

From man 2 mmap:

> ENOMEM No memory is available, or the process's maximum number of
>   mappings would have been exceeded.

So it seems that for whatever reason OS cannot fulfill loader request for memory. Either some limits are used(systemd, process limit, some security LKM, whatever) or simply there are not enough free memory in kernel.

To determine what object file generates most part of the BSS - use

```
objdump -j '.bss' -t *.o
```

Comment: Thank you very much for a clean answer. Actually I think I am not using that much huge amount of global/static variables. Could you please suggest how to debug the reason for 6GB BSS (or) the file which is causing this (or) the symbol (or) anything.

Comment: @Karthik try to use objdump -t and look for .bss section on target binary. If .bss section is already compressed by linker, then do the same thing for separate object files, that are built into the final binary by your linker editor(usually ld).

Comment: In my code, I had used two arrays of structure (128000 * 12000). The size of these is approximately 1.5 GB. After removing this, the size of bss came down to 2GB from 6GB. But I could not understand how this happened. why the .bss was 6GB earlier when the array size was just 1.5GB. How it was reduced by 4GB when I removed just 1.5GB. Could you please clarify.

Comment: @Karthik, you have to determine size of different sections inside your binary and then look into sections with biggest size.

Comment: 99% of total 6GB needed by the elf belongs to bss. 99% of size of bss belongs to a specific structure as shown by objdump. But the structure is just having elements for 2GB max. I removed an array of size 1.5G in the structure and the size of bss came down to 2GB. - this is what I could not understand. btw, I tried pragma pack(1) and compiling without -g. But these make no difference.

Comment: @Karthik, please show structure definition and objdump output. Also you can use pahole utility to dive into.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. :) Actually, I had declared an array of structure. The array size was 4 and the sizeof structure was 1.5GB. - and so the total 6GB.  It was my human error that I was thinking the size of array is just 1 and so wondering how bss showed 6GB when the variable was just 1.5GB.