# Linux - misunderstanding of how execv function loads new program

Tags: linux, unix, exec, execv

I am currently learning about Linux, and have a question about the execv function.

My understanding is that the execv function doesn't create a new process (fork does this), but instead the new program code of the program we wish to run gets replaced in the memory locations of the current process and also the new stack, heap etc.

What I can't seem to find an answer for is , what if the new program code and data etc. is much larger than the memory image of currently executing process? Does the OS resize the memory image for the new process or how would it work?

Is there perhaps a pre-defined memory image size under linux for every process?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Related: [Application is getting killed without any reason. Suspecting high BSS.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40212587/application-is-getting-killed-without-any-reason-suspecting-high-bss-how-to-de). Most programs start out life as a small dynamic loader. execv will only rarely fail because of lack of memory (ENOMEM). But the loader can then fail shortly thereafter if the program is too large - more detail in the linked question.

Comment: "Most programs start out life as a small dynamic loader" , this I don't understand.

Comment: The answer to that and the background for it is rather long to answer here, but see [lwn.net: How programs get run: ELF binaries](https://lwn.net/Articles/631631/) for more details. You're likely execing a dynamically-linked ELF file these days. In that case, the kernel does not load in the entire ELF file during exec. Instead, it looks at the header of the ELF file for the pathname of an  *interpreter*. On Linux, this is something like `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`, a small dynamic loader program. That is what the kernel loads into memory.

Comment: I apologize for putting what could constitute an answer in the comments, but I started out only meaning to augment a link to a related question on stackoverflow.com.